# Calling external API / Function from JD Edwards (JDE) web service (BSSV)

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client, webservice-client, jdedwards

We need to update order status to php based system using jd edwards web services. we need to make a call to below API from JDE web service.

sample code to call API from PHP is below...Similar logic we will need to use into JDE business service...

FIELD      DESCRIPTION                           SAMPLE VALUES
key        Identification token                  12334566
order      Order identification number           3008
json       (Optional) 0 to get XML response, 
                      1 to get JSON response     0

Parameters can be provided using GET properties, POST properties, XML or JSON.

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://[enter server name/ip]/client_api/update_order/', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$r->addPostFields(array(
    'key' => '12334566',
    'order' => '3008',
    'json' => 0
));
try {
    echo $r->send()->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

This call will send status code response if correct/failure.

Any suggestion for possible ways to do this and any samples???

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite easy, just write your C function that call a custom JDE web service and wrap a java http get (using the standard java api) to call your backend. I don'y have an full example but you can follow the Oracle guide for BSSV consumer and search over the internet for the java http get.